# How can I split the value of a column per comma?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
-- mytable
+----+------------+
| id |   value    |
+----+------------+
| 1  | one,ten    |
| 2  | nine,two   |
| 3  | five, one  |
+----+------------+
```

The value of `value` column is always made of two parts which are combined with `,`. Now I want to select them in two separated column like this:

```
-- expected result:
+----+-------+------+
| id | val1  | val2 |
+----+-------+------+
| 1  | one   | ten  |
| 2  | nine  | two  |
| 3  | five  | one  |
+----+-------+------+
```

How can I do that?

---

I can do that by PHP like this:

```
-- query
SELECT id, value FROM mytable

-- then
$vals = explode(",", $rows['value']);
foreach($vals as $val){
  //do stuff
}
```

But I want to know is that possible to I do that in mysql?

Comment: Your table design voids **1NF** .. fix that first

Comment: @Pரதீப் What does **"1NF"** mean? Also that's not the design of my table, it's actually what a function returns. I have to combine them because mysql functions return only one value. Now I need to split them.

Comment: *I have a table like this* this statement lead me to write that comment.. INF means storing atomic value in a column not more than one value..

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the function `INSTR()` to find the position of the comma and then use `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` to split these into the two columns you need, as below:

```
SELECT id
,LEFT(value,INSTR(value,',')-1) AS val1
,RIGHT(value,CHAR_LENGTH(value)-INSTR(value,',')-1) AS val2
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be done by using `SUBSTRING_INDEX(string,delimiter,count)` like this:

```
SELECT id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,',', 1) as val1,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,',', -1) as val2
FROM mytable
```